# Simple Rewind for AVAudioplayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I've got valuechanged event handler like that:

```
-(void)scrub:(id)sender
{
    if(self.audioPlayer.playing)
    {
        self.audioPlayer.pause;
        self.audioPlayer.currentTime=self.scrubber.value;
        self.audioPlayer.play;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't rewind happen? what should I add? thanks!
Moreover, how to display current time in a label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the time, you can do:

```
           [audioPlayer setTime:self.scrubber.value];
```

However, you need to verify that that is actually a number.  You also need to make sure it has an appropriate time for the file you are using.  I don't know what kind of scrubber you are using.  If setCurrentTime doesn't work, there is some problem with your scrubber.

If you are using a UISlider, you can do something like this to set the time:

```
            double value = progressSlider.value;
            double newSeekTime = (value / 100.0) * audioPlayer.duration;

            [audioPlayer setCurrentTime:(int)newSeekTime];
```

To get the time, you simply do audioPlayer.currentTime.  This is an NSTimeInterval, which is just a double.  To display the time, you can do:

```
            NSString *positionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d / %.2d:%.2d",
                                                                    (NSInteger)progress/60,
                                                                    (NSInteger)progress%60,
                                                                    (NSInteger)duration/60,
                                                                    (NSInteger)duration%60];
            myLabel.text = positionString;
```