# Easy ios audio library?

Tags: ios, audio

I'm looking for some iOS library that is easy to implement in my project.  I want to play long mp3 files (like audio books) stored on the device. The main issue is fast rewind of such long audio files. Looking for any help! Thx in advance!

Comment: The problem you speak of is difficult in any audio library.  Any compressed file without a time index built-in will have this problem, as it isn't possible to accurate seek in the file without decoding it.  This is especially true with VBR files.

Comment: I have a project with AVAudioPlayer. When I want to rewind from start to the end of one hour song I wait 5 secs. But I'v seen a player on AppStore that rewinds in one moment everywhere! How have they achieved it?

Comment: They make a guess as to where the seek point will be, based on file size and average bitrate.  It isn't exact, but is often close.

Comment: Well, I think "close" will be okay for me. Can you provide me with any useful links? I'v tried some libs but they were too complicated...

Comment: I'm not an iOS developer, but it shouldn't matter what you are using to play, as long as you can feed it a buffer of data.  `fileLengthInBytes / averageBitrate = totalTime`  You could probably just clip the file arbitrarily... most MPEG libraries will ignore bad data until the next frame.  (Otherwise, you will have to split on a proper frame, and deal with the bit reservoir... a real hassle.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use core audio APIs, have a look at [Core Audio Utility Sample App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of ur question , I guess 
they used Avaudioplayer library

[simple rewind for avaudioplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157533/simple-rewind-for-avaudioplayer)

Comment: I have the very same solution for rewind. It is slow!